# Find subsequent ID rows within certain date

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`,

```
ID        purchase_date       duration       end_date      1_month    
1          2021-04-03            4          2021-04-07    2021-05-07     
1          2021-05-01            7          2021-05-08    2021-06-08
2          2021-07-01            10         2021-07-11    2021-08-11
1          2021-07-05            5          2021-07-10    2021-08-10
```

What I want to do is have an additional column called `left` whereby if the customer has a subsequent purchase within the date of the `1_month` they are assigned 0 and if they do not make a purchase they are assigned 1. Like the below `df`.

```
ID        purchase_date       duration       end_date      1_month      left
1          2021-04-03            4          2021-04-07    2021-05-07     0   
1          2021-05-01            7          2021-05-08    2021-06-08     1
2          2021-07-01            10         2021-07-11    2021-08-11     1
1          2021-07-05            5          2021-07-10    2021-08-10     1
```

Effectively I need to take the `1_month` column, groupby ID and see if they have any future purchases within the '1 month' window since this row of data, this needs to work with customers who both have no subsequent purchases and those who have multiple purchases.

A primary issue with this question is that almost 50% of customers only have 1 row of data as they only make 1 purchase. These IDs should also be given a `left` value `=1` as they do not return within the `1_month` window. As purchases only range from 2021-01-01 to 2022-01-01 all purchases by customers, including their last purchase needs to be evaluated to see if there is ever a gap in purchases greater than 30 days.

Comment: what is the format of the date? DD-MM-YY? MM-DD-YY? Can you explicit which dates are used in the comparison (ideally break down all comparisons for the example)?

Comment: Hi I've edited the question sorry about that the date format is now correct on the post

Answer (score 1):

```
df['left']=np.where(df['purchase_date'] < df['1_month'].shift(-1), 0, 1)
df
```

```
    ID  purchase_date   duration    end_date    1_month     left
0   1   2021-04-03            4     2021-04-07  2021-05-07  0
1   1   2021-05-01            7     2021-05-08  2021-06-08  1
```

Comment: Hi this seemed to work for id's with multiple rows but all the ids with only 1 row who should be assigned 1 were assigned 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to be able to identify a future date per ID.

I provided a more complex input to better see the result:

```
df['left'] = (pd
 .merge_asof(df.sort_values(by='1_month'),
             df.sort_values(by='purchase_date'),
             left_on='1_month',
             right_on='purchase_date',
             suffixes=(None, '_next')
             )
 .eval('~(purchase_date_next>purchase_date)')
 .astype(int)
)
```

output:

```
   ID purchase_date duration   end_date    1_month  left
0   1    2021-04-03        4 2021-04-07 2021-05-07     0
1   1    2021-05-01        7 2021-05-08 2021-06-08     1
2   1    2022-05-01        x 2022-05-08 2022-06-08     1
3   1    2022-06-01        x 2022-06-08 2022-07-08     0
4   2    2021-05-01        x 2021-05-08 2021-06-08     1
```

used input:

```
   ID purchase_date duration   end_date    1_month
0   1    2021-04-03        4 2021-04-07 2021-05-07
1   1    2021-05-01        7 2021-05-08 2021-06-08
2   1    2022-05-01        x 2022-05-08 2022-06-08
3   1    2022-06-01        x 2022-06-08 2022-07-08
4   2    2021-05-01        x 2021-05-08 2021-06-08
```

Comment: This works great for multi purchase ID but has the same issue with customers who only have 1 purchase where it doesnt seem to assign them a value of 1

Comment: Can you provide an example for which it happens? (input + expected output)

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_sort = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'purchase_date', '1_month'])


def check(x, d):
    y = d.loc[x.name]
    if not math.isnan(y['ID']) and x['end_date'] <= y['purchase_date'] <= x['1_month'] and y['ID'] == x['ID']:
        return 0
    return 1


df_sort['left'] = df_sort.apply(lambda x, d=df_sort.shift(-1): check(x, d), axis=1)

print(df_sort.sort_index())
```

**output:**

```
    ID purchase_date  duration    end_date     1_month  left
0   1    2021-04-03         4  2021-04-07  2021-05-07     0
1   1    2021-05-01         7  2021-05-08  2021-06-08     1
2   2    2021-07-01        10  2021-07-11  2021-08-11     1
3   1    2021-07-05         5  2021-07-10  2021-08-10     1
```

Comment: I get this error when I try and run the code unfortunetly. "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'"

Comment: sorry for that, when creating df with read_clipboard it automatically converts values to strings... I've altered my answer. You have to import math.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting an error this time TypeError: must be real number, not str on the last but one line with the df_sort.apply

Comment: I wonder, what are the last line values. On my system, I get nan for y['ID'], that's why I'm checking for math.isnan(y['ID']) first inside the function' condition.

Comment: Yeah I've been lost on this project for a few weeks :'( thank you for trying to help!